# Regex to enforce character set

Tags: regex, character-encoding

I'm having difficulty writing a regex to enforce a custom character set. I want the regex to match only in every character in the string is part of the defined set. It's easy enough to match one string in the set; the trouble seems to be in making sure the regex doesn't match if a bad character is passed in.

Here's the regex:

```
[\u0000-\u00FF\u20AC\u0160\u0161\u017D\u017E\u0152\u0153\u0178]
```

This **will** match "Hello World!" (good)

It **will not** match "雙喜" (good)

It **will** match Hello World! 雙喜 (not good)

I'm sure I am just missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: If you want "only" these characters, you just have to do `/^[\u0000-\u00FF]*$/` (I abbreviated "allowed characters" a little bit.)  Just added the "from start to finish, only these characters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex just checks if there is at least one character in your pattern that matches.

Try `^[\u0000-\u00FF\u20AC\u0160\u0161\u017D\u017E\u0152\u0153\u0178]*$` instead. (Between the start, ^, and the end, $, there may be any number of characters that belong to the range, but no others).

Comment: You are a lifesaver. It was the *$ that I missed. Many thanks.

Comment: Don't forget the ^ at the start ;)

Comment: Yes, I saw that too. Thanks!